Pitch, yaw and roll from rotation matrix of two images
I am currently trying to develop a little program that determines the pitch, yaw an roll the camera has moved between two images. (see my following example)
First Image

Second Image

My approach on that was to first use OpenCVs SIFT function to find the same points on each image, get the homography matrix using RANSAC, decompose that matrix and then extract the rotation matrix and get the angles for pitch, yaw and roll.
When running my code it provides me with the angles but they don't seem to make any sense. For example, I took a picture with 20° pitch but it gave me a 1.4° pitch.
Since I am kinda new to this field I am currently trying to figure out where my problem is. Is it the extraction from the rotation matrix or is it even earlier when calculating the homography matrix?
Here my code:
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Resize images to fixed size
def resizeImages(image1, image2, target_size):
    resized_img1 = cv2.resize(image1, target_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    resized_img2 = cv2.resize(image2, target_size, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return resized_img1, resized_img2

# Extract pitch, yaw and roll from rotation matrix
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R):

    # Sine of pitch angle
    sy = math.sqrt(R[0, 0] * R[0, 0] + R[1, 0] * R[1, 0])

    if sy < 1e-6:
        singular = True
    else:
        singular = False

    if not singular:
        x = math.atan2(R[2, 1], R[2, 2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1, 0], R[0, 0])
    else:
        x = math.atan2(-R[1, 2], R[1, 1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2, 0], sy)
        z = 0

    return np.array([x, y, z])


MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

img1 = cv2.imread('IMG_2084.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('IMG_2085.png')

# Resize images to a fixed size
target_size = (800, 600)
img1, img2 = resizeImages(img1, img2, target_size)

img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

keypoints_1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1_gray, None)
keypoints_2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2_gray, None)

matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k=2)

good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

if len(good_matches) >= MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([keypoints_1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([keypoints_2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    H, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 1.0)


    focal_length = 26
    cx = img1_gray.shape[1] / 2
    cy = img1_gray.shape[0] / 2
    K = np.array([[focal_length, 0, cx], [0, focal_length, cy], [0, 0, 1]])

    # Decompose homography matrix
    _, rotations, translations, normals = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(H, K)

    # Extract the rotation matrix and convert to angles
    rotation_matrix = rotations[0]
    print(rotation_matrix)

    # Extract the rotation matrix and convert to Euler angles
    eulerAngles = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(rotation_matrix)
    pitch = eulerAngles[0]
    yaw = eulerAngles[1]
    roll = eulerAngles[2]

    print("Pitch (X-axis rotation):", pitch)
    print("Yaw (Y-axis rotation):", yaw)
    print("Roll (Z-axis rotation):", roll)

else:
    print(f"Not enough matches are found - {len(good_matches)}/{MIN_MATCH_COUNT}")

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints_1, img2, keypoints_2, good_matches, None,
                       flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

cv2.imshow('SIFT', img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Thanks in advance :)
I also tried using the function as_euler() from scipy but I still have issues with extracting the corrects angles.
   r = R.from_matrix(rotation_matrix)
    euler_angles_deg = r.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)

    roll_angle = euler_angles_deg[0]
    pitch_angle = euler_angles_deg[1]
    yaw_angle = euler_angles_deg[2]


Hi, OpenCV doesn't give you global coordinates. It returns second pose transformation from the first pose. Thus 4 degrees sounds very reasonable.
